# How to access MySQL database using static IP over internet?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have one computer in that MySQL is install and that have a static IP and that is connect to internet. How to access the MySQL database in that pc in another pc over internet?

Comment: [link 1](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,188267,191867), [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065125/how-to-access-a-remote-mysql-database-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

In the config.inc.php file of PHPMyAdmin set the following line

Original:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'localhost';
```

Your version:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']      = 'your_servers_static_public_ip';
```

Set `your_servers_static_public_ip` to the public IP address of your server.

If you are using a firewall then you need to remember to open the port 3306 in your firewall to allow remote MySQL requests to reach MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html) is a section on connecting to MySQL from the manual.

So, you would use --host and --port.

Also, you would need to configure your firewall to let this traffic pass though, and also possibly the MySQL server to allow connections from external IPs.